# WinForms UserControl can't Focus properly

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, focus

I have a WinForms UserControl that accepts keyboard input, and had a Scrollbar for scrolling, and everything was fine. Recently I swapped the Scrollbar control out for a custom scrollbar (also a UserControl), and now after clicking the custom scrollbar, my custom control loses focus and the only way to get it back is to click a different focusable control (like a TextBox) and then click back in my UserControl. If the scrollbar has focus and I click inside my UserControl to give it focus, I notice the LostFocus event is raised and the scrollbar keeps the focus

I tried setting the UserControl's Selectable control style to true, it didn't help.

Any idea why it would behave this way?

Comment: `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);` in the Constructor of the scrollbar UC. And/or its child Controls. -- Set it again + `UpdateStyles()` if you destroy handles, at some point.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I am still able to select the scrollbar. Its CanSelect value is now false but CanFocus is still true. And when I check the ActiveControl property, I can see the focus has gone to the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.ContainerControl, false);
```

In the UserControl's constructor. Because it had the ContainerControl flag set by default, it would preferentially give the focus to a child control.